# How to Make Separate Space in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

How to make a separate space?

Example: I want make ASCII to Hex

> Hello - 48656C6C6F

But I want it formatted like this

> Hello - 48 65 6C 6C 6F

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Or on one line

```
Dim hex = String.Join(" ", "Hello" _
    .Select(Function(c) Convert.ToByte(c).ToString("x2")))
```

without the `Replace`.

---

If you want to show the high bytes (because each `Char` is actually two `Byte`s because strings are Unicode)

```
Dim hex = String.Join(" ", "Hello" _
    .SelectMany(Function(c) BitConvertor.GetBytes(c)) _
    .Select(Function(b) b.ToString("x2")))
```

Comment: another great code! Thanks but how to make if using checkbox??

Comment: @user1961795, the seperator is the first parameter to `String.Join`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Encoding.ASCII`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.ascii.aspx) and the [`BitConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) class.

```
Dim asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello")
Dim hex = BitConverter.ToString(asciiBytes).Replace("-", " ")
```

`hex` is now `48 65 6C 6C 6F`

Comment: Thanks for help!! but i got problem!

Sorry if i make more request but how to make it if using checkbox!!

if checkbox true then = enable space

if false = disable space

how to make that ?? Sorry asking more because me still newbie :(

Comment: `Dim hex = BitConverter.ToString(asciiBytes).Replace("-", If(checkbox1.Checked, " ", ""))`. But please consider asking a seperate question in future if you encounter other problems :-)

Comment: @user1961795, thats a different question.

Comment: @Dominic Kexel .. Wow you so professional.. Thanks so much! Another Useful code! Copied! :)